# TestNg cannot proceed to next test method when one Jemmy test is completed

Tags: java, testng, jemmy

I am using Jemmy in TestNg to test a Java swing application
But when my first test method completes execution, my application closes down and in eclipse console the execution is stopped but in TestNg runs tab the test run is not completed but it won't move on to test the second test method.